# Django |safe template filter

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is there a way to specify characters that shouldn't be escaped is Django templates.

I have the following Copyright® I don't want Django to escape the &reg ; is there a filter to do that?

The workaround I've used to prevent XSS attacks is:

```
{{object.title|safe|striptags}}
```

Is there a better solution than this?